# What are they using for lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lately I have been seeing this on several websites (facebook, TOI etc), which seem like async lazy loading of content. The css appears first with a moving busy-wait effect and then sometime later content loads up.

[image]

I know this is an async ajax call that is populating the data. My question is, is this plain simple ajax call with busy-wait css effect or is there any special library that is providing this type of functionality? The reason why I ask is because I am seeing exact same effect on several websites. Either all of them are really good at copying this effect or there is a standard library.

Much Thanks,

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: I know this is an ajax call that is populating the data. my question is, is this plain simple ajax call with busy-wait css effect or is there any special javascript library that is providing this type of functionality?

Comment: In the case of Times of India, it's right there in the source: `@keyframes thumb_animation{from{box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3)}to{box-shadow:inset 80px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3)}}`. It's a CSS animation.

Comment: Thanks @p4sh4 for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please point me to library that they are using to do this?

This is just a placeholder animation that populates the area before the actual content is rendered in.

You can implement this by having an animated `gif`, for example, that is the default content of the element and when the actual content is loaded, it simply takes the place of that animated `gif`.

This concept is the same as having a loading wheel while you wait for content to load.

> And what is this called?

The content is usually loaded in with some sort of `AJAX` request. If you're new to the concept of `AJAX`, feel free to learn more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/).

`AJAX` is basically data that is being rendered asynchronously on a webpage.

**NOTE:**

To answer your question regarding a specific library that does this, I don't know of any. The core concept is simple - have *something* populating your elements before the data is ready, and when the data is ready simply replace the content.

I think those particular sites just have their own implementation of that effect, as I'm guessing it's pretty trivial to create if you're really good with animation.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Can you please  respond to my edited question?

Comment: @TheWanderer Just did - see my edit. Basically I don't think there is a library that'll do this for you, rather you just have to make that animation yourself.

Comment: Thanks Nick for editing your answer. That's why I posted this question to confirm with the community because I didn't know of any special library as well.

Comment: @TheWanderer Glad I could help! Honestly, making your own animation for this effect is the fun part =)